# Do I have to write an HTTPMODULE for my SharePoint Instance?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want my users to type http://mysitehosturl/username and see their profiles (mysite). Do I need to write an HTTPModule for this and if so, I would appreciate for a tutorial about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to go with Httpmodule. Refer [this link](http://vspug.com/dwise/2007/01/08/one-master-to-rule-them-all-two-actually/) it should help you to get started. Article is based on 2007 but same concept applies to 2010 as well.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I made it somehow after discovering remote debugging. My handler was working but I couldn't get the RawURL at first. Now it works with a handler.

Comment: There is an option in sharepoint 2010 on mysitehost template settings to do this as we desire but It DOES NOT WORK :(